# UNICODE Regex in java

Tags: java, regex, unicode, pattern-matching

In a combined regex it looks like working and it is failing when am using it in pattern.  please help.

```
^(?=.*\\p{Nd})(?=.*\\p{L})(?!.*(.{2,})\\1).{5,12}$
```

this seems to be working but when I split it's failing.

```
^(?=.*\\p{Nd})(?=.*\\p{L})
```

Also I am looking for UNICODE validation to ignore any special character and just accept mixture of letters/Alpha & digits (atleast one alpha and one digit)

```
public void setValidations(){
        validation1 = "^(?=.*\\p{Nd})(?=.*\\p{L})"; //this is failing
        validation2 = "^.{5,12}$";
        validation3 = "(\\S+?)\\1";
        p1 = Pattern.compile(validation1);
        p3 = Pattern.compile(validation3);
    }
    public boolean validateString(String str){
        matcher1 = p1.matcher(str);
        matcher3 = p3.matcher(str);
        if(matcher1.find()){ //Expecting string passed "invalid" to fail (no numeric in it)
            System.out.println(str + " String must have letters & number at least one");
            return false;
        }
        if (!str.matches(validation2)){
            System.out.println(str  + " String must be between 5 and 12 chars in length");
            return false;
        }
        if (matcher3.find()){
            System.out.println(str + " got repeated: " + matcher3.group(1) + " String must not contain any immediate repeated sequence of characters");
            return false;    
        }
        return true;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringValidation sv = new StringValidation();
    String s2[] = {"1newAb", "A1DOALDO", "1234567AaAaAaAa", "123456ab3434", "$1214134abA", "invalid"};
    boolean b3;
    for(int i=0; i<s2.length; i++){
       b3 = s2[i].matches("^(?=.*\\p{Nd})(?=.*\\p{L})(?!.*(.{2,})\\1).{5,12}$");

       System.out.println(s2[i] +  "  "+ b3); // string "invalid" returning false (expected)
    }
    for (String str : s2) {
            if(sv.validateString(str))
                System.out.println(str + "String is Valid");
    }
}
```

Also I want "$1214134abA" this string to fail since it has $

Comment: Could you please supply a set of samples along with whether you want each item to pass/fail your regex?

Comment: am passing list of strings as examples and more samples could be: VԀअs1 (valid)
Vd$s1 (invalid)
Vdab1 (valid)

Comment: @user1769790 your first if condition is true if a match is found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pattern.compile("^(?=.*\\p{Nd})(?=.*\\p{L})").matcher("invalid").find()` returns false as `"invalid"` does not contain a digit. Thus the `if` condition is evaluated to false and that block is skipped.

Use `^(?=[\\p{Nd}\\p{L}]*\\p{Nd})(?=[\\p{Nd}\\p{L}]*\\p{L})` to avoid characters other than letters and digits.

It will not accept `$1214134abA` as it contains `$`.

Comment: just tried as is
if(Pattern.compile("^(?=[\\p{Nd}\\p{L}]*\\p{Nd})(?=[\\p{Nd}\\p{L}]*\\p{L})").matcher(str).find()){
System.out.println(str + " String must consist of a mixture of letters and numerical digits only, with at least one of each");
}
It returns invalid string for valid strings like:
A1DOALDO, 1234567AaAaAaAa, 123456ab3434

Comment: @user1769790 add negation to the if condition. now it is true if a match is found!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you forgot to use negation in

```
if(matcher1.find()){ //Expecting
    ... 
    return false;
}
```

It should return false if it ***will not*** find match. Try with

```
if(!matcher1.find()){ //Expecting...
```

Also since you want to check if your entire string is build on letters and digits instead of `.{5,12}` at the end try `[\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]{5,12}` .

Comment: that's right!! and am choosing Naveed's as answer and upvoting here.

Comment: Thank you!  You know all my issues by now :)